# MySQL4 on a Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, ufw, mysql4

I am using CAO faktura 1.4 which only works with mysql4,
so I installed mysql4.1.22 on a Raspberry Pi 4 B
which was a bit tricky but finaly I managed to configure and make install.

Then I added to the [mysqld] section of the my.cnf the following line

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I also grant the root user access from remote

```
grant all on *.* to root@'%.%.%.%' identified by 'mypass';
```

I checked with

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

everything looks fine.

but when I try to connect from my windows machine with mysql workbench via tcp/ip
It tells me "Failed to connect"

I also created another user and granted all privileges from remote but that didn't work either.

I checked for firewall but Raspberry OS doesn't come with a firewall preinstalled.(as far as I know)
Then I installed ufw and allowed tcp connections on port 3307 which is also declared in the my.cnf

But nothing worked. I dont get it, why can i not connect?

EDIT:

when trying to telnet It seems like i get a connection at first with some weird symbols...
but after 3 seconds it tells me connections lost.

```
4.1.22mysql4-log♥aGzV}2~I,☻0R..:vg$vMYW

Connection to host lost.
```

Here is the MySQL4 error log

```
231019 21:23:42  mysqld started
231019 21:23:42  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44138
/usr/local/mysql4/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '4.1.22mysql4-log'  socket: '/usr/local/mysql4/var/mysqld.sock'  port: 3307  Source distribution
```

Comment: MySQL 4.1.22? That version is 17 years old

Comment: I very much doubt current MySQL Workbench will be compatible with such an old version. Can you ping your Pi from your windows machine? Do you get a response if you attempt to telnet to it - `telnet <Pi's ip> 3307`?

Comment: @user1191247 I added the telnet results at the end of my question.

Comment: As expected, you are able to connect to the server. Unsurprisingly, Workbench is not compatible with the old server. You could try the old [GUI Tools](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/gui/) or possibly another client like [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/), but you will still need to find a suitably old version of libmysql.dll. Why do you want to run `CAO faktura 1.4`? Running software that old has so many potential issues.

Comment: oh thats it. with the old GUI Tools it connected right away no problem...
Thank you alot! @user1191247
Well actually I do not use CAO faktura 1.4 thats why I couldn't test it.
I installed the server for a good friend of mine. He uses CAO faktura 1.4 for probably more than 20 years now he had a IT Company and got smaller the last years to the point he only produces one product, a control unit for servos. He is used to it and don't want to buy the newer version...

Comment: But now when I think about it, buying a Raspberry, sd card, case and power supply is not that much cheaper :D well it's installed now and he gets what he wants...

Comment: Impressive you were able to run this at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by user1191247. The server was running, I just used the wrong software to connect to it.

MySQL Workbench can't connect to older MySQL Servers with the old [GUI Tools](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/gui/) It was no problem to connect to my MySQL 4.1.22 Server.